# UI Popup Opacity Mask JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, menu, popup, fxml

Is it possible with [`Popup`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Popup.html) opacity mask top and bottom JavaFX? I have `TextField` autocomplete with `Popup`. So the idea is to put an opacity mask.

Comment: To be honest, I was not familiar with the term "opacity mask". But even after looking it up, I'm not sure how you want this applied to an auto-complete popup. Do you want the bottom of the popup to fade away? You could make the background do that easily, but I'm not sure if you could make all the content fade with it. Is there any way you could offer an example of what you want the end result to look like? Preferably accompanied by a [mre] that _doesn't_ do what you want.

Comment: I found this little code snippet https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/07/javafx-tip-31-masking-clipping-alpha-channel.html - Not sure if PopUP extends LayoutChidren

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know clips could do that (or I forgot). Could you still provide a [mre] though? Figuring out how to apply this to your code requires us to be able to see an example of your code. In particular, do you have access to the popup? And what type of popup is it (`Popup` or `PopupControl`)? We probably need more details regarding the exact expected behavior as well.

Comment: I will reproduce this in my code and post it here soon. Okay, @Slaw?

Comment: @JoseTeixeira that clipping article from Dirk that you linked is very interesting, I did not know that clips could be so flexible and make use of alpha blending.

Answer (score 3):

Below is another way you can give a try, for getting the opacity masked effect. Though it is not exactly the same implementation, I took some ideas from the link you provided :).

I created a small utility where you can pass the Popup instance. The utility builds the mask panes and include to the root node of the Popup.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PopupOpacityMaskDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:grey;");
        root.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            ListView<String> content = new ListView<>();
            content.getItems().addAll(IntStream.range(100, 200).mapToObj(i -> i + "").collect(Collectors.toList()));
            content.setPrefSize(200, 250);

            Popup popup = new Popup();
            popup.setAutoHide(true);
            popup.getContent().add(content);
            popup.setX(e.getScreenX());
            popup.setY(e.getScreenY());
            popup.show(root.getScene().getWindow());
            MaskUtil.applyMask(popup);
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    static class MaskUtil{
        static void applyMask(Popup popup) {
            double fadeSize = 70;
            Pane pane = (Pane)popup.getScene().getRoot();

            // Build the mask panes
            Pane topMask = buildMaskPane(pane, fadeSize, false);
            Pane bottomMask = buildMaskPane(pane, fadeSize, true);

            // Just ensuring to remove any masks (if you are reusing the Popup)
            pane.getChildren().removeAll(pane.lookupAll(".mask"));
            pane.getChildren().addAll(topMask, bottomMask);

            // Update the bottom mask position by listening to height of pane
            pane.heightProperty().addListener((obs, old, h) -> bottomMask.setLayoutY(h.doubleValue() - fadeSize));
            if (pane.getHeight() > 0) {
                bottomMask.setLayoutY(pane.getHeight() - fadeSize);
            }
        }

        private static Pane buildMaskPane(Pane pane, double fadeSize, boolean isBottom) {
            Pane mask = new Pane();
            mask.setMouseTransparent(true); // Turn this to 'false' if you don't want to interact over mask
            mask.setPrefHeight(fadeSize);
            mask.prefWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
            mask.maxHeightProperty().bind(mask.prefHeightProperty());
            mask.minHeightProperty().bind(mask.prefHeightProperty());
            mask.getStyleClass().add("mask");
            mask.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to %s, #555555, transparent)", isBottom ? "top" : "bottom"));
            return mask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Nice, Sai Dandem ! Thanks You !